# UTM Parameters in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Email Links

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio

We have utm-parameters attached to email links for emails going out through marketing cloud. Where are these parameters configured in the marketing cloud?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you will need to create a case with Marketing Cloud Support with a request to apply the utm-parameters to your account in order to have them appended to email links.

Comment: Thanks @zeljazouli! That was my understanding! I just wanted to make sure that they are configured on the back end as they were not visible on the UI anywhere. We already have them configured and they are set at the email level as _AdditionalEmailAttribute(n)